# How can destination addresses 132.148.77.28 and 132.148.77.28/32 be use different network interfaces for routing?

Tags: routing, freebsd, netstat, ip-routing, cidr

The output of `netstat -rn` on my FreeBSD virtual machine shows that:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags      Netif Expire
default            10.195.51.254      UGS      vtnet0
10.195.48.0/22     link#1             U        vtnet0
10.195.49.46       link#1             UHS         lo0
127.0.0.1          link#2             UH          lo0
132.148.77.28      link#1             UHS         lo0
132.148.77.28/32   link#1             U        vtnet0
```

Given the CIDR of `32`, doesn't `132.148.77.28/32` equal `132.148.77.28`?  If so, how do packets to the destination address in question decide whether to use `lo0` or `vtnet0` since there's two different routes defined for that address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `H` flag indicates a route to a particular host, which will be used in preference to a route to a subnet.

It looks like the main subnet for `vtnet0` is `10.195.48.0/22`, and `132.148.77.28` is just an alias (hence the `/32`).

See the manual pages for [netstat(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat) and [route(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=route&sektion=8&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+11.0-RELEASE+and+Ports).

Comment: Is the Netif column for the interface that the packet is coming from?  As in, any packet passing through lo0 bound for 132.148.77.28 will send it to link#1, and any packet passing through vtnet0 bound for 132.148.77.28 will also send it to link#1?  OR, are you saying that it doesn't matter where it comes from, the preferred route will always be the one with UHS flags - in which case what would the Netif value do?

Comment: A packet arriving on any interface for the host has arrived and doesn't need to be routed anywhere.  If you need a deeper understanding of the network interface, you could look at The Design and Implementation of the FreeBSD Operating System (book)