# In the output of netstat -r, what is the meaning of the "Netif" column and how does it differ to the "Gateway" column?

Tags: routing, gateway, route, netstat, ip-routing

I can find virtually no documentation of the meaning of the column "Netif" in the output of `netstat -rn`.  Googled for it, searched through the [netstat(1)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=netstat&sektion=1) and [route(8)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=route&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+8.3-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) man pages and found the following sentence as the clearest bit of information on the meaning of the column:

> The interface (Netif column) that this routing table specifies to use for localhost is lo0, also known as the loopback device. This says to keep all traffic for this destination internal, rather than sending it out over the LAN, since it will only end up back where it started.

Found this explanation here: https://www.dragonflybsd.org/~labthug/handbook/network-routing.html

I currently have a pending question on severfault [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/832039/how-can-destination-addresses-132-148-77-28-and-132-148-77-28-32-be-use-differen) in which I've got a couple lines from my `netstat -rn` output on a FreeBSD machine:

```
Destination        Gateway            Flags      Netif Expire
...
132.148.77.28      link#1             UHS         lo0
132.148.77.28/32   link#1             U        vtnet0
```

My understanding, from the FreeBSD handbook on [Gateways and Routes](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/en_US.ISO8859-1/books/handbook/network-routing.html) is that

> The route indicates that when trying to get to the specified destination, send the packets through the specified gateway...There are also three types of gateways: individual hosts, interfaces, also called links, and Ethernet hardware (MAC) addresses.

`link#1` refers to the interface `vtnet0`, which is the first to show up when running `ifconfig`.  That being said, I would think I could read my first route as "When trying to reach 132.148.77.28, use interface vtnet0."  But then what the heck does `lo0` mean in the "Netif" column?  Also, related to the other question I've got pending right now, if both destinations are identical (the second seems to be an alias), it seems like it might prefer the first one since it comes first, but under what conditions would it skip it and go on to the second one?

Comment: It stands for "network interface".